# How to highlight a datagridview row when a character is typed in the search textbox

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, datagridview

Using a textbox to search a value in a given datagridview column, the code below position the selected row on the column containing the text typed.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
        //{
            for (int i = 0; i < (productDataGridView.Rows.Count); i++)
            {

                if (productDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().StartsWith(textBox1.Text, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    productDataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell = productDataGridView[1, i];
                    productDataGridView.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    return; // stop looping 
                }
            }
     }
```

The problem is that I cannot highlight or change the back color of the required row while typing in the textbox, any help please?

Comment: Don't believe FirstDisplayedCell sets the row to current. Tried setting productDataGridView[1,i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor...  reather than CurrentRow?

Comment: That's true FirstDisplayedCell doesn't set the row to current, is there a way to set it to current?

Comment: productDataGridView.CurrentRow = ...

Comment: doesn't work since it is read only property.

Comment: I'm on phone, guessing. But *you* could try to Google: 'Set Current DataGridView Row'. I bet the first hit gives you the answer.

Comment: John, I have already done that before ask my question here, it is hard to find, but as I tried several methods, now I am closer to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried this solution, this finally works like a charm:

```
            try
        {
            productDataGridView.ClearSelection();   //or restore rows backcolor to default
            for (int i = 0; i < (productDataGridView.Rows.Count); i++)
            {
                if (productDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString().StartsWith(textBox1.Text, true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    productDataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i;
                    productDataGridView.Rows[i].Selected = true; //It is also possible to color the row backgroud
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        { 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
      //restore backcolor of rows to default e.g. loop through grid and set backcolor to white
       foreach(DataGridViewRow row in productDataGridView.Rows)
        {
           if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().StartsWith(textBox1.Text, true,     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                //productDataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell = productDataGridView[1, i];
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                return; // stop looping 
            }
            else
              //Set backcolor to default
        }

        //return; //move return here
```

Comment: Tried this method, the back color changes only when the textbox content is found in only one row not more. The second problem the row remains coloured in spite of textbox content has been changed.

Comment: the first problem is because you put `return`. The second problem is you have to restore the backcolor to their default state before running this code. check updated answer

Comment: It is not possible to remove return, I get exception. Tried: productDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White; doesn't restore the color to their default state.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. Put return outside the loop if the method has a return type. You might need to loop through the grid to restore it to default backcolor or put an else statement in the loop

Comment: Removing Return as advised gives the exception: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled, it is better to reset back color of rows before if statement. The big problem here is that a row might be highlighted without being displayed.